# HSQLDB is eating all my memory

Tags: java, jpa, hsqldb

I'm using a HSQLDB for an application that stores research data and there is quite a lot of data. HSQLDB insists on always loading the tables into memory. I've tried fixing this by setting hsqldb.default_table_type=cached in my persistence.xml but that does not work.

Is this the wrong place?

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="Dvh DB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.willcodejavaforfood.dvh.entity.Patient</class>
    <class>com.willcodejavaforfood.dvh.entity.Plan</class>
    <class>com.willcodejavaforfood.dvh.entity.Dvh</class>
    <class>com.willcodejavaforfood.dvh.entity.ImportSession</class>
    <class>com.willcodejavaforfood.dvh.entity.Project</class>
    <class>com.willcodejavaforfood.dvh.entity.Course</class>
    <class>com.willcodejavaforfood.dvh.entity.Property</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:./myDvhDb"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hsqldb.default_table_type" value="cached" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

When my HSQLDB database is created I can see in its properties file:

```
hsqldb.default_table_type=memory
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try putting the `hsqldb.default_table_type=cached` in the connection string? Like this: `jdbc:hsqldb:./myDvhDb;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached`

Comment: I ended up using the hibernate.connection.hsqldb.default_table_type property, but I guess that is what you meant so you get credit :)